# How to add height and weight in database using PHP?

Tags: php

I had created the table with height,weight and age in db.But I had a problem in creating the height and weight and inserting the values.Please anyone help me.

This is the code:

```
 <?php
  $installer = $this;
   $installer->startSetup();
   $installer->run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mg_childgrowth(
  gender varchar(60) NOT NULL,  
  height int(60) NOT NULL,
  weight int(60) NOT NULL,
   );");

 Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->setId(null);
 $installer->endSetup();

<?
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Why do you need 60 digits of height and weight? How fat are your users?

Comment: @Barmar doesn't the need for 60 digits answer that? ;P

Comment: This creates the table with height and weight as `INT` columns. What did you try to insert values? Btw, `Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->setId(null);` does nothing

Comment: Oh, looks like the code was fixed by an edit, which changed the meaning of the question. I rolled it back...

Comment: OK.I got the answer.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

set height and weight to varchar because it may contain decimal values

```
 $installer->run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mg_childgrowth(
 gender varchar(60) NOT NULL,  
 height varchar(60) NOT NULL,
 weight varchar(60) NOT NULL,
 );");
```

Comment: Why not use `DECIMAL` or `FLOAT`?

Comment: How to use decimal or float can you please suggest me.

Comment: its just a suggesion. we can use decimal or float also.

Comment: @Mouni in place of varchar for height and weight in my answer use decimal or float what ever you want.

Comment: If I need to add height in feet and inches then how can I need to add

Comment: you can set varchar if your height will contain characters like inch.

Comment: If I set varchar then Can I insert the values  like 5'7".

Comment: yes it is possible varchar will insert all characters and numbers.